# Getting the Row data from the SQL after executing the query statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL statement which inserts data into a row. The row id would be automatically incremented.

But how do I get back that row of data which got inserted and executed?  That row of data should includes the row id which I no idea of what that is..

I want the whole row $row, not just the id.   I don't know the id because it's autoincremented.

Comment: Do you just want the row id or do you need the entire row? (Note: If you have the id, you could easily use that to fetch the rest of the row if you need it.)

Comment: This very dependent on the DB. For example SQL server has the output clause. You need to tell us what you're using to answer this

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an autoincremented id you can use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

E.g.

```
INSERT INTO supportContacts
(type, details)
VALUES
('Twitter', '@sqlfiddle');

SELECT * FROM 
supportContacts 
WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c787/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an auto-incrementing column for the id, the following will work in any database:

```
select *
from table
where id = (select max(id) from table)
```

Under the assumption that no one else is inserting rows.

In SQL Server, you can do the following:

```
declare @id int;

insert . . .

select @id = @@Identity;

select *
from table
where id = @id;
```

Just note that the line with @@Identity needs to follow immediately after the insert.

Comment: -1 `MAX(ID)` = Race condtion. `@@IDENTITY` = Race Condition as well. You should use SCOPE_IDENTITY to retrieve the ID if you need it. But the [OUTPUT CLAUSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) is much better in this context if its SQL Server

Comment: I see the race condition for the max(), which is why I qualified the statement.  I don't see the race condition for @@IDENTITY.  This is assigned within a session.  Can you explain why there's a race condition?

Comment: I've seen problems with @@identity, due to there being insert triggers on the table that I was dealing with.  Better to use the function ident_current('tablename') (again, assuming SQL Server)

Comment: @GordonLinoff  [from MSDN](@@IDENTITY (Transact-SQL))  @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the value only within the current scope; **@@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.** The easiest way to see this in action is to create an insert trigger that inserts into a different table. (It may have been an overstatement to call it a race condition)

Comment: Besides race conditions, `MAX(ID)` will give wrong result in some other (not so common) cases: With master-master replication and also with negative(!) auto-increment.

Comment: I interpreted the question as needing a fast-and-dirty way to get recently loaded data.  I totally agree that the output clause is a better way to put this information into an application.  Also, triggers cause problems with @@IDENTITY.  However, IDENTITY is limited by the current scope, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx.  So, for a user who inserts records and just wants to see them right away, my solution is quite reasonable.